# Using mathematical induction to prove Inverse rule for groups elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question is:

> Use **mathematical induction** to prove that if  $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are elements of a group $G$ then $$(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^{-1} = a_n^{-1}a_{n-1}^{-1}\cdots a_1^{-1}$$

May attempts:

Starting with a base case where $k=2$ we have $a_1$,$a_2~~$ $(a_1,a_2)^{-1}=e$

we multiply out by $(a_2)^{-1} (a_1)^{-1} a_1,a_2 (a_1,a_2)^{-1}= (a_2)^{-1} (a_1)^{-1} e$

and get 
$e*e*(a_1,a_2)^{-1}=(a_2)^{-1}(a_1)^{-1}$

now i assume true for the $k$-th case and want to show it for the $k+1$ case

${(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)^{-1}} = (a_k)^{-1},\ldots,(a_1)^{-1}$

now i multiply by $(a_{k+1})^{-1}$

$(a_{k+1})^{-1} * {(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)^{-1}} = (a_{k+1})^{-1} * (a_k)^{-1},\ldots,(a_1)^{-1}$

My main question being is can i treat $(a_{k+1})^{-1}$ as one item and ${(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)^{-1}}$ as anther item say $(a_d)^{-1}$ and convert it into  $(a_d,a_{k+1} )^{-1} = (a_{k+1})^{-1} * (a_k)^{-1},\ldots,(a_1)^{-1}$

Does this finish the proof?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila It's not magical anymore :(

Comment: @David: ?${}{}$

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I went to edit it but after entering I stopped. Sorry...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Was a joke; you edited "mathi *magical*" to "mathematical".

Comment: I am a physics student it will always be magic :)

Comment: @David: I only removed the [elementary-set-theory] tag.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, sorry...

Comment: @Faust7 Assuming that I read your mathematics correctly, then this looks fine. Everything you write in English makes perfect sense, and that is the way of proving your claim. Yout TeX-ing could use some work, though. Here are the [guidelines](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) for writing mathematics here on math.SE.

Comment: yeah i had some serious problems getting the $a_{k+1}$ to have an inverse sign on it

Comment: @Faust7 : Please: Get a LaTeX manual.  And look at the ways in which some others have improved your posting.  Some of your ways of using LaTeX are bizarre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's precisely the idea. Your inductive step is a bit shakey though. This is how you write it out. You've got the base case, $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$.  For the $k$ case, you can take $a=a_1\cdots a_{k-1}$ and $b=a_k$.  So you've got $$(a_1\cdots a_{k-1}a_k)^{-1}=((a_1\cdots a_{k-1})(a_k))^{-1}=a_k^{-1}(a_1\cdots a_{k-1})^{-1}.$$  By inductive hypothesis $$(a_1\cdots a_{k-1})^{-1}=a_{k-1}^{-1}\cdots a_1^{-1},$$ so $$(a_1\cdots a_{k-1}a_k)^{-1}=a_k^{-1}a_{k-1}^{-1}\cdots a_1^{-1},$$ and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Below is the essence of the inductive step, with $\rm\: x' = x^{-1}$

$\rm\begin{eqnarray}\qquad  &&\ \rm (ab\cdots\! &\rm y& &\rm\!\! z)  (z'& &\rm\! y'&\rm\! \cdots b'a')\\
\rm &=&\ \rm  (ab\cdots\! &\rm y&\!\!)&\rm\! z\ \ z'&\!\!(&\rm\! y'&\rm\!\cdots b'a')\quad by\  associativity\\
\rm &=&\ \rm  (ab\cdots\! &\rm y&\!\!)&\ 1&\!\!(&\rm\! y'&\rm\!\cdots b'a')\quad by\, \ zz' = 1\\
\end{eqnarray}$

The prior $ = 1$ by the induction hypothesis, after absorbing the $1$. Ditto in the other order.